# Add checkbox value to another hidden input field if first hidden field has content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a group of 4 checkboxes.

When any two have been checked they have their values copied to two hidden input fields.

The first checked checkbox value goes to the first input `id="checkedBox1"`

How do I get the second checked checkbox value to go to the second hidden input field `id="checkedBox2"`

I have used the JavaScript function below to place the values into each input from the individual checkboxes but can't figure out how to iterate through the list of all four checkboxes and place the two checked ones into each separate input field.

**Checkboxes:**

```
<input type="checkbox" value="test1" id="a" name="one"><label>Test11</label>
<input type="checkbox" value="test2" id="b" name="one"><label>Test12</label>
<input type="checkbox" value="test3" id="c" name="one"><label>Test13</label>
<input type="checkbox" value="test4" id="d" name="one"><label>Test14</label>

  <input type="hidden" value="" id="checkedBox1">
  <input type="hidden" value="" id="checkedBox2">

<script>
function populate() {
  var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('one');
  var ip1 = document.getElementById('checkedBox1');
  var ip2 = document.getElementById('checkedBox2');

  // clear current values
  ip1.value = ip2.value = '';

  var first = false;
  var second = false;

  // Loop over checkboxes,stop when found 2 that are checked
  for (var i=0,iLen=checkboxes.length; i<iLen || !(first && second); i++) {

  if (checkboxes[i].checked) {

  if (!first) {
    ip1.value = checkboxes[i].value;
    first = true;

  } else if (!second) {
    ip2.value = checkboxes[i].value;
    second = true;
  }
  }
  }
  }

 $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
 populate();
 }).change();
 </script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try plain JS, though I would use form property access rather than *getElementsByName* or *getElementById*:

```
function populate() {
  var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('one');
  var ip1 = document.getElementById('checkedBox1');
  var ip2 = document.getElementById('checkedBox2');

  // clear current values
  ip1.value = ip2.value = '';

  var first = false;
  var second = false;

  // Loop over checkboxes,stop when found 2 that are checked
  for (var i=0,iLen=checkboxes.length; i<iLen || !(first && second); i++) {

    if (checkboxes[i].checked) {

      if (!first) {
        ip1.value = checkboxes[i].value;
        first = true;

      } else if (!second) {
        ip2.value = checkboxes[i].value;
        second = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### Edit

Thanks Mal, added a line to clear the values of the hidden inputs each time.

Comment: This works great if you select the checkboxes right the first go. If you uncheck and recheck new values with out refreshing the page it gets `first` and `second` mixed up.

Comment: Thanks Rob and Mal for your help with this. I have just been able to get this working in my live version based on the edited OP code above. Works perfectly. Thanks again.